# How to deploy Smart Contract to Azure Ethereum Consortium (POA)

Tags: ethereum, remix

I have created a Ethereum Blockchain on Azure BaaS service- Proof Of Authority consensus algorithm.
I hit an issue here, when I try to deploy a Smart Contract to the blockchain network via the provided RPC endpoint. It complains that I don't have enough Ether to do so. Can someone advise that, how could I get ether for the Admin account? Obviously, the account cannot mint ethers and this is not the POW algorithm.
Please advise.
Thank you.

Comment: Did you see anything in Azure UI during the POA setup? I believe it must be somewhere in the setup wizard where you can set ETH balance for certain addresses.

Answer (score 0):

Are you working with truffle? If so, take the following advice to see if can help you.

You can only deploy the smart contracts to ethereum PoA on Azure with truffle version 5.0.5. Latest version of truffle gives gas cost related issues.

For me downgrading the truffle version solved the problem:

npm i -g truffle@v5.0.5